# Connecting to oracle: Using PDO works but using oci_connect not

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

**Working code-**

```
$dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/XE', 'hr', 'hr');
$s = $dbh->prepare("select * from Employees");
$s->execute();
while (($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) != false) {
    echo htmlentities($r['FIRST_NAME']) . " " . $r['LAST_NAME'] . "<br>";
}
```

**Not working code** ***(Error-Call to undefined function oci_connect(),  oci_new_connect())***

```
/*Using oci_connect */
$conn=oci_connect("hr","hr","localhost/XE");
If (!$conn)
    echo 'Failed to connect to Oracle';
else 
    echo 'Succesfully connected with Oracle DB';

oci_close($conn);

/*Using oci_new_connect*/

$c = oci_new_connect('hr', 'hr', 'localhost/XE');
$s = oci_parse($c, 'select city from locations');
oci_execute($s);
while (($res = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
 echo htmlentities($res['CITY']) . "<br>";
}
```

phpinfo are as [phpinfo details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Abbg.png)
I have placed instantclient for 11g in c and set PATH variable also

---

**Tried every instantclient extensions one by one-**

1. extension=php_oci8.dll,
2. extension=php_oci8_11g.dll,
3. extension=php_oci8_12c.dll

**I am using Oracle 11g**

Tried also- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249858/how-to-enable-extensions-for-oci8-oracle-in-php-ini-php-warning-php-startup) and [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519686/install-and-configure-oci8-to-connect-oracle-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

OCI_CONNECT required TNSNAMES.ORA file on server. Hostname (as IP) only works if domain controller register name.

```
      <?php
      $oracleHost="IP or Hostname";
      $oracleLogin="username";
      $oraclePassword="passworrd";
      $oraclePort="1521";
      $oracleSid="sidname";
      $tns="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$oracleHost)(PORT=$oraclePort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$oracleSid)))";$oracleConnect = oci_connect($oracleLogin,$oraclePassword, $tns);
      ?>
```