# How to conncect Oracle with PHP under Winginx?

Tags: php, oracle, winginx

I want to use PHP to connect to Oracle, but get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()...

I searched in Google, and get that the OCI is not enabled in PHP, but after `install Ora10InstantClient & enable extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` , I still get the error.

I checked phpinfo(), found the "configure command" -> with-oci8-12c= ... was **WRONG**. How do I fix this path? If this is not this problem, how can I resolve the problem?

[image]

Comment: perhaps this link may helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249858/how-to-enable-extensions-for-oci8-oracle-in-php-ini-php-warning-php-startup

Comment: I think i resolve the problem,Winginx use 64bit, but i install Oracle Client(32bit),so change the client ,it's OK now,thank you!